# How to get cookie after login using mechanize

Tags: python, mechanize-python

```
import mechanize
import json
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

browser = mechanize.Browser()
class login:
    def __init__(self):
        email = "aaaa"
        password = "bbb"
        url = "https://app.propertymeld.com/login/?next=/"
        self.email = email
        self.password= password
        self.url = url
    def login_url(self):
        try:
            browser.open(self.url)
            browser.select_form(nr=0)
            browser.form['email'] = self.email
            browser.form['password'] = self.password
            result = browser.submit().read()
            print(result)
            print("Login Successfully")
        except Exception as e:
            print("Unable to login successfully",e)

def main():
    web_login = login()
    web_login.login_url()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I need to get the cookies after logging in a webpage, using a particular email and password with mechanize. How can I get the browser's cookies in a particular login session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the cookies from `browser._ua_handlers['_cookies'].cookiejar`.
This returns a `mechanize._clientcookie.CookieJar` object which can be iterated through and there are names and values for each of the cookies in it.

For instance, the first cookie's name and value are:
`browser._ua_handlers['_cookies'].cookiejar[0].name`
`browser._ua_handlers['_cookies'].cookiejar[0].value`